# Moment.js Date Validation

Tags: node.js, momentjs

Here is some code taken from the chrome console. It looks like moment.js isn't forcing the 'year' paramater to be 4 characters even though that's what I stated in the format.

```
date
"16/01/14"
moment( date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid()
true
```

In short try

```
moment( "16/01/14", 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid()
```

I would expect this to be false, but it's true. Is there anyway to force moment to be more restrictive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/ :

> Moment's parser is very forgiving, and this can lead to undesired behavior. As of version 2.3.0, you may specify a boolean for the last argument to make Moment use strict parsing. Strict parsing requires that the format and input match exactly.

```
moment( "16/01/14", 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid()
> false
```